# problems inserting top row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df called table and I would like to insert a list of 0s as the first row.

```
table:
                A         B         C           D
 Date
 2016-04-21  0.020068  0.027631  0.006116   0.005451
 2016-04-22  0.008741  0.006732 -0.013585   0.003863
 2016-04-25 -0.020516 -0.020339 -0.007526  -0.010102
 2016-04-26  0.051630  0.032790  0.008437   0.015524
```

I made a function no create a list of 0s of length = number of headers.

```
def arr():
   arr = []
   for i in range(len(list(table()))):
       arr.append(0)
   return arr

pd.DataFrame([arr()],columns=list(table()))

print(table())
```

gives the error :

```
Shape of passed values is (1, 1), indices imply (4, 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First need create new index value, [add new row](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#setting-with-enlargement) to `df` by `loc` and last [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df.loc[df.index[0] - pd.offsets.DateOffset(days=1)] = 0
df = df.sort_index()
print (df)
                   A         B         C         D
Date                                              
2016-04-20  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
2016-04-21  0.020068  0.027631  0.006116  0.005451
2016-04-22  0.008741  0.006732 -0.013585  0.003863
2016-04-25 -0.020516 -0.020339 -0.007526 -0.010102
2016-04-26  0.051630  0.032790  0.008437  0.015524
```

Comment: Always great jezrael

Comment: Glad can help you. ;)